# Why are Java Optionals immutable?

Tags: java, option-type

I'd like to understand why Java 8 Optionals were designed to be immutable.  Is it just for thread-safety?

Comment: Many things in Java are immutable, usually for performance.

Comment: Immutability has gained a lot of popularity in recent years due to many advantages like thread safety and an overall lower risk of creating bugs. Also it's more compatible with the functional programming paradigm which Java 8 is supposed to embrace.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Optional is not immutable for performance reasons, immutability is a core aspect of its design - it stands in for the value of a reference, after all. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html

Comment: What would possibly be gained by making it mutable?

Comment: @pvg `String` is immutable (and so are the wrapper types, largely) for performance reasons, and is another example of a **Value-based Class**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - String is also immutable for reasons of simplicity (of behavior, use, reasoning) and security.  The only way you could make a convincing fact-based argument as to the *main reason* why String is immutable is if you could cite sources written by the original Java design team.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think either of these things are accurate. String does not meet the definition of a value-based class nor was performance the primary motivation for its immutability. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195099/why-is-string-immutable-in-java

Comment: @StephenC It's an example where not one (but two) **mutable** `String`(s) exist (`StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`). I *think* I agree with your *reasons*, but I might stipulate that simplicity extends to implementation of a performant runtime.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I don't discount performance as a significant issue.  Note the word "also" in my earlier comment.

Comment: @pvg - Unless you can find a >>definitive<< source to back up your opinion, then it is just that ... an opinion.  In this case, definitive means written by someone on the relevant Java design team stating >>their<< reasons for the design choice.

Comment: @StephenC that's an absurd criterion. You can infer the design goals of String from a basic familiarity with the history of Java's development, the suggestion there is no way to do that without explicit confirmation from someone on the design team is strange, to put it mildly. Especially since immutability itself is _trade off_ ,in terms of performance - there are many situations in which mutable strings perform better.

Comment: No.  What I said is that your opinion is an opinion.  And no more correct that someone else's opinion.  Or at least, not unless you are prepared to make a fully argued case, backed up by proper sources ... or empirical measurements.  (Which would be difficult.)  Hint 1: Your inferred design goals are inferred with the benefit of hindsight ... which the original designers did not have.  Hint 2:  the design for `String` was almost certainly made with the consideration of *multiple* factors ... one of which was performance.  That applies for `Optional` too.

Comment: @StephenC I'm sorry, your argument is still absurd. And an opinion can easily be more correct than another opinion. Nor did I say performance was not a consideration, it's just not the main one. But if you insist, take a look at http://www.artima.com/intv/gosling313.html . Before you tell me 'caching' is about performance, mutability doesn't prevent caching, it it interferes with the _reliability_ of caching. And the clincher - security, with the key quote 'That precise [security] example is what really demanded that Strings be immutable.'

Comment: Yes.  One opinion can be more correct valid than another.  But up until the last comments, your argument was little more than an >>assertion<< that your opinion was more correct ... or that Elliott's was incorrect.  Which is not a valid argument.  FWIW, my recollection was also that security was the primary reason for making String immutable.  It doesn't apply to other types though.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I suspect that as Java evolves that performance will become more important.  Immutability (or more precisely immutability of value types) can be exploited by the compiler to enable various optimizations in the context of the support for functional programming idioms that is increasingly being added to the Java language / libraries.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch usually object are made immutable to improve clarity and thread safety. Objects are made *mutable* for performance.  Can you explain how String being immutable helps performance and why we use StringBuilder if it is slower?

Comment: @StephenC that is utterly inaccurate. The position I was espousing is a well-understood, well-accepted one. It is you who introduced a 'teach the controversy' criterion here, but there is not an iota of controversy about this. Immutability, in general, is an invariant introduced for the purpose of _correctness_ fist and foremost. In the case of concurrency, I'll refer you to section 3.4 of _Java Concurrency in Practice_. The statement I was objecting to was 'Many things in Java are immutable, usually for performance'. This is inaccurate. It is especially inaccurate in the case of `Optional`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Optionals are for passing things around.  If you give something to someone and then change its contents, they will be very surprised, and not in a good way.

Comment: Having read more about this and realized that, despite the (obvious) freedom to use Optionals for whatever purpose one deems sufficient, they were primarily designed to be wrappers for method return values, your answer seems the most right in terms of design intent.

Answer (score 7):

Optional is considered a value object, and should be immutable to help reduce their ability to make you pull your hair out tracking down a bug at 3am. You can read here for a bit more on the topic:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObjectsShouldBeImmutable

Comment: Being a "value" object is silly argument for making it immutable IMO. In rust, all type are value by default and mutability is allowed.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh in Rust you can enforce at an API layer that a parameter or return value is immutable; in fact you need to explicitly opt in for mutability. That's not a thing in Java. Mutability can be a performance optimization when it's really needed but immutability is almost always safer. In fact that's one of the main reasons people use Rust.